# Not Able to get Radio button value into Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs.I have a form where i have multiple row of radio button and textboxes.But i am not able to get value of radio button in controller.My Code:

HTML:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="consentinfo in listofdata" ng-disabled="abc">
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="consentinfo.consentType"></input></td>
   <td>
      <input id="radio-1{{$index}}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group{{$index}}" ng-value="consentinfo.option1" ng-model="radio1" type="radio" ng-click="radio()">
      <label for="radio-1{{$index}}" class="radio-custom-label">Yes</label>
      <input id="radio-2{{$index}}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group{{$index}}" ng-value="consentinfo.option2" ng-model="radio2" type="radio" ng-click="radio()">
      <label for="radio-2{{$index}}" class="radio-custom-label">No</label>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="consentinfo.expDate" class="form-control date" readonly>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="consentinfo.submittedDate" class="form-control date" readonly>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="consentinfo.shortDescription"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="consentinfo.longDescription"></td>
</tr>
```

.JS File:

```
var consentManagerApp = angular.module('consentManager', []);
consentManagerApp.controller('dataOwnerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.listofdata = [{
                    "consentType": "Do you consent for us to use your  private data for KF Searches",

                    "expDate": "14-12-2017",
                    "submittedDate": "24-04-2017",
                    "option1": "true",
                    "option2": "false",
                    "status": true,
                },
                {
                    "consentType": "Consent to be contacted",

                    "expDate": "10-10-2017",
                    "submittedDate": "12-02-2017",
                    "option1": "true",
                    "option2": "false",
                    "status": true,
                },
                {
                    "consentType": "Consent to be solicited",

                    "expDate": "06-08-2017",
                    "submittedDate": "02-12-2017",
                    "option1": "true",
                    "option2": "false",
                    "status": true,
                },
                {
                    "consentType": "Consent to participate in Trend studies",

                    "expDate": "10-11-2017",
                    "submittedDate": "12-02-2017",
                    "option1": "true",
                    "option2": "false",
                    "status": true,
                },
                {
                    "consentType": "Consent to participate in recruiting practice",

                    "expDate": "10-10-2017",
                    "submittedDate": "12-02-2017",
                    "option1": "true",
                    "option2": "false",
                    "status": true,
                }
            ];


            $scope.submitConsent = function() {

                alert('CTY=' + $scope.choices[0] + 'O2=' + $scope.choices[1]);
                alert('Listdata=' + $scope.radio1 + " " + "O2=" + $scope.radio2);




            }]);

        consentManagerApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml;
        });
```

Can any one guide me how i will be able to get the value .i need to persist it in database.

Regards,
Prabhash

Comment: can you please provide a `fiddle` ?

Comment: see the answer below. Be sure to tick it correct if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-value="{{consentinfo.option1}}"`, that will solve your problem for not getting the value of radio-button.

You have also missed one of the curly braces for your function `$scope.submitConsent`.

**EDIT: There are certain misconcepts on your plunker**

You need to assign your `ng-model` for radio dynamically, have a click function to see if you can access the value of radio button. Also, there were other hidden bugs like missing parenthesis. Run the snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body  ng-app="consentManager">
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      <div ng-controller="dataOwnerController">
         <table >
            <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="consentinfo in listofdata" ng-disabled="abc">
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="consentinfo.consentType" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input id="radio-1{{$index}}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group{{$index}}" ng-value="{{consentinfo.option1}}" ng-model="radio[consentinfo.expDate]" type="radio" ng-click="callClick(radio[consentinfo.expDate])" />
                     <label for="radio-1{{$index}}" class="radio-custom-label">Yes</label>
                     <input id="radio-2{{$index}}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group{{$index}}" ng-value="{{consentinfo.option2}}" ng-model="radio[consentinfo.expDate]" type="radio" ng-click="callClick(radio[consentinfo.expDate])" />
                     <label for="radio-2{{$index}}" class="radio-custom-label">No</label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" ng-model="consentinfo.expDate" class="form-control date" readonly="" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" ng-model="consentinfo.submittedDate" class="form-control date" readonly="" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="consentinfo.shortDescription" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="consentinfo.longDescription" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <button ng-click="submitConsent()">submit</button>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">

      var consentManagerApp = angular.module('consentManager', []);
      consentManagerApp.controller('dataOwnerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.radio1;
        $scope.radio2;
                  $scope.listofdata = [{
                          "consentType": "Do you consent for us to use your  private data for KF Searches",
                          "expDate": "14-12-2017",
                          "submittedDate": "24-04-2017",
                          "option1": "true",
                          "option2": "false",
                          "status": true,
                      },
                      {
                          "consentType": "Consent to be contacted",
      
                          "expDate": "10-10-2017",
                          "submittedDate": "12-02-2017",
                          "option1": "true",
                          "option2": "false",
                          "status": true,
                      },
                      {
                          "consentType": "Consent to be solicited",
      
                          "expDate": "06-08-2017",
                          "submittedDate": "02-12-2017",
                          "option1": "true",
                          "option2": "false",
                          "status": true,
                      },
                      {
                          "consentType": "Consent to participate in Trend studies",
      
                          "expDate": "10-11-2017",
                          "submittedDate": "12-02-2017",
                          "option1": "true",
                          "option2": "false",
                          "status": true,
                      },
                      {
                          "consentType": "Consent to participate in recruiting practice",
      
                          "expDate": "10-10-2017",
                          "submittedDate": "12-02-2017",
                          "option1": "true",
                          "option2": "false",
                          "status": true,
                      }
                  ];
      
                  $scope.callClick = function(value){
                    alert(value);
                  }
                  $scope.submitConsent = function() {
                        
                      // alert('CTY=' + $scope.choices[0] + 'O2=' + $scope.choices[1]);
                      // alert('Listdata=' + $scope.radio1 + " " + "O2=" + $scope.radio2);
      
      
                  }
      
                  }]);
      
              consentManagerApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
                  return $sce.trustAsHtml;
              });
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I make the changes and i am passing consentinfo.option1,consentinfo.option2 to my .js file where i am writing $scope.option1 and $scope.option2 but it is coming undefined.

Comment: @PrabhashMishra can you share your form code as well?

Comment: Requirement is first textbox value and two date value will come from database on page init.The radio button value and last two text value the user will be able to enter .Thats why i am trying to enter value in radio button and last two text box.I know how to get static entry of radio and text box.But here it is dynamic.I tried with listofdata[$index] but it was not working with last two textbox.Can you give me how ng-repeat dynamic field is accessed in angularjs.

Comment: instead of passing radio value on button click i am passing same radio[consentinfo.expDate] in submitConsent(radio[consentinfo.expDate]) but value in controller is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input id="radio-1{{$index}}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group{{$index}}" ng-value="consentinfo.option1" ng-model="consentinfo.option1" type="radio" ng-click="radio()">
```

replace ng-modal="radio1" to  ng-model="consentinfo.option1"
ng-modal="radio2" to  ng-model="consentinfo.option2"

Comment: I make the changes and i am passing consentinfo.option1,consentinfo.option2 to my .js file where i am writing $scope.option1 and $scope.option2 but it is coming undefined.